# exception-when-using-system-diagnostics-process-start-to-open-an-RPT-file

Tags: c#, .net, .net-framework-version

Similarly to the question asked in  : [Exception when using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start to open an EML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74817756/exception-when-using-system-diagnostics-process-start-to-open-an-eml-file)

I have an issue with open a crystal reports file and i would like to atleast give the user the pop dialog asking which app they would like to open with.

I use this code to currently open file :

`Process proc = new Process(); proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path); proc.Start();`

I am using the dot net framework 4.6

I tried this solution that I found
//New Format to allow all files to be opened

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.FileName = path;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                startInfo.Verb = "";
              
                Process.Start(startInfo);
```

but the error is still there.